# Fit cell width to content with overflow support

Tags: css

Given the following markup, how can I achieve both 1) stretched and fit content width cells 2) the overflow working. I can do the first step but the overflow doesn't respond properly because width isn't explicitly defined. Below is what I have done to stretch the fourth cell and make others width the same as content.

```
.first, .second, .third{
        width: 1%;
        white-space: nowrap
      }
```

```
<table>     
  <tr>
    <td class="first"><i class="gg-trash"></td>
    <td class="second"><i class="gg-check-r"></i></td>
    <td class="third"><i class="gg-more-vertical-alt"></i></td>
    <td class="fourth">
      <div>A LOT OF TEXT</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This code doesn't allow me to manage overflow in this way:

```
.fourth > div {
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }
```

All I want is ellipsis alongside the stretch feature, It works if I have `table {table-layout: fixed}` but then I lose the ability of fit content width. OR can I make cells to have width as of their content in fixed table-layout?

IF NOTHING THEN PLEASE AT LEAST TELL ME: I managed to do this using javascript, first find the width then applied it explicitly, then added the text. Should I be doing it in this way, cuz it's just some static page content.

Comment: are you sure that you want to display tabular data? If not, then do not use a table!

Comment: tables naturally grows to fit their contents. div doesn't, but yours has no width nor max-width set, so it stretches its parent's cell according to its content. give the div a size or max-size, it should triggers texxt-overflow.

Comment: @tacoshy Yes, this is tabular data. Every row will represent an email the same way as the first one. I used tables because they provide the easiest way for center aligning icons, not even flex can.